# Passing data from android to Backend via SOAP

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have to create an expense to a dynamics backend using soap. I'm currently on the same network so no authentification is needed yet. The service takes (date, amount, currency, user) as paramters, but I can't seem to even get connection to the webservice. Can anyone help me?

MyActivity

```
import com.example.KsoapExample.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private TextView txt;
private String celsius;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value_to_convert);
    final EditText edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    final EditText edt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (edt.length() > 0) {
                createRecord(edt.getText().toString(), Integer
                        .parseInt(edt2.getText().toString()), edt3
                        .getText().toString());
            } else {
                txt.setText("values can not be empty.");
            }
        }
    });
}

public Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case 0:
            txt.setText(celsius);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

private final void createRecord(final String date, final int i,
        final String user) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SoapRequests ex = new SoapRequests();
            celsius = ex.getResponse(date, i, user);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

SoapRequests Activity

```
    package com.example.KsoapExample;

import android.util.Log;
import org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SoapRequests {

    private static final boolean DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE = true;
    private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "LOCAL HOST";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String SESSION_ID;

    private final void testHttpResponse(HttpTransportSE ht) {
        ht.debug = DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
        if (DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE) {
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + ht.requestDump);
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + ht.responseDump);
        }
    }

    public String getResponse(String date, int expense, String user) {
        String data = null;
        String methodname = "createRecord";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
        request.addProperty("Date", date);
        request.addProperty("Expense", expense);
        request.addProperty("User", user);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodname, envelope);
            testHttpResponse(ht);
            SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<HeaderProperty> COOKIE_HEADER = (List<HeaderProperty>) ht
                    .getServiceConnection().getResponseProperties();

            for (int i = 0; i < COOKIE_HEADER.size(); i++) {
                String key = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getKey();
                String value = COOKIE_HEADER.get(i).getValue();

                if (key != null && key.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
                    SoapRequests.SESSION_ID = value.trim();
                    Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Cookie :" + SoapRequests.SESSION_ID);
                    break;
                }
            }
            data = resultsString.toString();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception q) {
            q.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        return envelope;
    }

    private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,
                MAIN_REQUEST_URL, 60000);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
        return ht;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final List<HeaderProperty> getHeader() {
        List<HeaderProperty> header = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
        HeaderProperty headerPropertyObj = new HeaderProperty("cookie",
                SoapRequests.SESSION_ID);
        header.add(headerPropertyObj);
        return header;
    }
}
```

XML for MyActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value_to_convert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/date"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number|text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/amount"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/user"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:hint="@string/response"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: SOAP...Really...fall back to REST and your life would be wonderful. If no fallback allowed, add a server side component in between the two. You call your server side in REST + JSON and your server side does SOAP to your target WS. Much better that doing SOAP from android.

Comment: I'm going to put SOAP in the grave and focus on REST then :) DO you have any thoughts on how to pmplement this with REST (I'm not very familiar with it).

Comment: Just Use your simple PHP or Java based Servlets or controllers and instead of returning HTML change content type to application/json and return a json text. You can do the same thing with XML also. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html should get you started. Which server side language are you using java or PHP?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm only developing the android applikation and therefore I do not know exactly what is used on the server side. But I got the REST thing going and now get a Authentification error (which is expected because I have no authorization yet). So my approch from here on will be:
-Request tokens needed to implement in header
-Add to header so that I can now access the webservice to post expenses 
??

Comment: you need authentication header added. I cant help on this more without details.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a little vague. I have to call a webservice via REST . The server that hosts the service is on premesis (http.://Work) and I can only get access to it if I add an authentification token to the header in the REST call. I have username and password to get auth-token on another server (https.://Auth) but I don't know how to request the token from the android device.

Comment: I guess its a 2 service call then. First service to get token from the authentication service. and then on the second service add the token in header of the REST request. Since headers are key=value pairs you need to find out the key for the auth token to be sent in the second REST call. Sometime such tokens are also shared as cookies or session parts. Depending you what your service side code of second REST call expects, add a header or cookie pair accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you very much Nazgul. I will certainly try this approach :)